# How to get a value from a javascript file to c#?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm using ASP.NET to make a website for a hotel and at this point to show the hotel rooms I've created a javacript file to generate div's, now I want to get the value of the room number that by clicking "learn more "transfer the value of the number of the room to the other page

I already tried to use cookies but it does not work

here's the js file that generates the div:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.get('http://localhost/quartos.php', function (data) {
    var results = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(results);

    for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var div = "<div class='col-sm col-md-6' height='600px' width='400px'><div class='room'><a href='' class='img d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center' style='background-image: url(images/Quartos/" + results[i].imagem + ");'></a><div class='text p-3 text-center><h3 class=' mb-3'><a href=''>Quarto " + results[i].descricao + "</a></h3 > <p><span class='price mr-20'>" + results[i].Preco_quarto + "\u20AC</span><asp:Label ID='Label1' runat='server' Text='ç aop'></asp:Label><span class='per'> por noite</span></p> <ul class='list'><li><span>Max:</span>" + results[i].Lotacao_Maxima + " Pessoas</li><li><span>Vista:</span>" + results[i].Vista + "</li></ul><hr><p class='pt-1'><button class='btn btn-primary' runat='server' onserverclick='btn_quartos'>Ver Detalhes<span class='icon-long-arrow-right'></button></span></p></div></div></div>";


        document.cookie = "CookieName=" + results[i].Num_Quarto + ";";

        $("#quartos").append(div);
    }
});
});
```

and the cs of the "next" page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string num_quarto = Request.Cookies["CookieName"].Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Is the `php` tag relevant? Either state how it's relevant to your question or remove it.

Comment: yes it is because the js data its based on a php file , its on the second line http://localhost/quartos.php

Comment: Anyway, please describe what's wrong with your current solution.

Comment: the cookie i used just return the last value of the query and i want to get the one i select

Comment: You're running PHP and ASP.NET in the same IIS site?

Comment: yes but i just use php to get the data of the rooms and pass it to js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting the cookie to something new each time in the for loop, so the cookie is always going to hold the last result in `results`, despite what they select.

Although, using a cookie to pass info from one page to another isn't an ideal way to do what you want anyway.

A better way would be to make your "learn more" page able to accept a room number as a query string value.

Example: `http://localhost/learnmore.php?cuarto=123`

Then that looks up the room information and renders the information into the html.

In doing that, you can simplify the link in your div element to point to `learmore.php?cuarto="+results[i].Num_Quarto` and not have to repurpose the cookie functionality for a behavior it's not really meant for.

Comment: Yes it works, i usually use Session to tranfer values between pages but in that case i think thats the unic option, ty